# TypeError: Object does not appear to be a file-like object

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to access a png file to add to the background of my matplotlib plot. I'm doing something like this:

```
fn = get_sample_data('Jupiterbackground.png', asfileobj=False)
img = read_png(fn)
```

but I'm receiving an error like this:
TypeError: Object does not appear to be a file-like object.
So I manually typed in the path file name to this png file to see if it would work, but it still didn't work, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with the type of file I've chosen. Or am I using a flawed method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried that too. I got the same type of error. But exactly the same thing can be done with:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg\
img = mpimg.imread('Jupiterbackground.png')
```

and this gives the image array a numpy array. Then if you want you can even change the datatype with `img.astype(#dataType)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please include your imports next time, I assume it is

```
from matplotlib._png import read_png
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
fn = get_sample_data('Jupiterbackground.png', asfileobj=False)
img = read_png(fn)
```

`fn` is a string because you used `asfileobj=False` (you can check this with `print(fn, type(fn))` which is often a good way to find `TypeErrors`) and `read_png` expects a file-object. You can either use `asfileobj=True` or call open on the string you get from `get_sample_data`.

I can not get `read_png` to work though and get "OSError: read past end of file". But the method is undocumented (as far as I could google) and its module name starts with an underscore, which in python conventions means it is not part of the public API (that is: it is a function for internal use by matplotlib)

Like the other answer said, use a different function to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by writing the whole path of the image file I want to open, like: `C\\...\\Jupiterbackground.png`.
I don't know why but if I didn't do it, I saw that the program searches for the file where the 'matplotlib' installation files are.